# Как конвертировать awk скрипт в sh скрипт

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sh

Есть простенький скрипт для подсчета среднего значения в колонке:

```
cat /home/data/hotels.csv | awk -F, '{sum+=$18} END {print sum/NR}'
```

Я хочу создать файл process.sh, чтобы он делал то же, самое, и принимал файл с датасетом в качестве аргумента:

```
./process.sh /home/data/hotels.csv
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: `cat $1 | awk -F, '{sum+=$18} END {print sum/NR}'`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, *Useless use of cat*...

Comment: @0andriy ну я просто скопировал текст из поста 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт process.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, '{sum+=$18} END {print sum/NR}' "${1:?Не передано имя файла}"
```

запуск

```
./process.sh /home/data/hotels.csv
```

Переводить из `awk` в `sh`ell, думаю смысла в данном случае нет

Comment: Неумение обрабатывать входной поток, это минус скрипту.

Comment: @0andriy `cat "${1:--}" | awk...` - ну тут лишний cat, да еще и в вопросе ни слова не было про конвеер

Answer (score 1):

Переделывать awk в sh не стоит, sh медленнее и не поддерживает дробные числа, которые будут появляться при вычислении среднего значения. Либо оберните awk в баш скрипт, как рекомендовал user341547, либо создайте awk скрипт.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
}

sum+=$18{}

END {
    print sum/NR
}
```

запуск

```
./process.awk /home/data/hotels.csv
```